# Store setInterval for clearing later

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, setinterval, intervals, clearinterval

I'm working on a jQuery plugin that utilises JavaScript intervals. However, when the plugin is called again with the argument `running` as `false`, then I want the previous interval called on that particular DOM element to be cleared.

Here is some shortened code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.examplePlugin = function (running) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (running === false) {
                // Clear the previous interval assigned to this DOM element
            } else {
                setInterval(function () {
                    // Interval code
                }, 50);
            }

           return this;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

How is this possible? I thought of using global variables to store the intervals but I don't really want to do that. I also don't have any clue how to assign an interval to a particular DOM element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save intervals per DOM element, then you'd be best off with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), which does exactly what you want - setting data on a particular DOM element.

```
var saved = $(this).data("__examplePlugin_interval");

if (saved) { // I think you mean when it *is* running
    clearInterval(saved);
    $(this).removeData("__examplePlugin_interval");
} else {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        // Interval code
    }, 50);

    // choose a name that won't be accidentally overwritten by others
    $(this).data("__examplePlugin_interval", interval);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's spot on!